# krantz class chapter and algorithm2e clash

Tags: chapters, algorithm2e

I am writing a book in `krantz`-class and get errors when using the `algorithm2e` package.

You can find the krantz class here https://github.com/yihui/knitr-book/blob/master/krantz.cls

And here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{krantz} 
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\chapter{What?}
Test.
\end{document}
```

Throws the error:

`! File ended while scanning use of \@chapter. I suspect you have forgotten a '}'`.

The `algorithm2e` documentation says that

> - FIX: krantz class changes definition of chapter and get one more
>         option that classical classes as book.cls or report.cls and
>         broke fix for hyperref on chapter definition. This is now
>         fixed and algorithm detects use of krantz class and use then
>         a definition of chapter working with krantz class.

I updated my `algorithm2e` package to the newest version, the error persists. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) since `krantz` does not seem to be a standard class (at least not known to CTAN), you might want to specify where one might get that class, otherwise it is near impossible to help

Answer (score 1):

The `algorithm2e` packages tries to hook into `krantz.cls`, but does so in a bad way (probably because of subsequent changes to the class).

```
% avoid some of the spurious warnings
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass{krantz}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% undo the "fix" by algorithm2e
\let\@chapter\algocf@original@chapter
% make a better fix
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
 {\addtocontents}
 {\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}\addtocontents}
 {}{}              
\makeatother

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\chapter{What?}
Test.
\end{document}
```

The numerous warnings

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000)
Overfull \hbox (312.25pt too wide)
```

are due to the class and should be fixed by its author.

Answer (score 0):

I found that modifying my code to

```
\RequirePackage{algorithm2e}
\documentclass{krantz}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\chapter{What?}
Test.
\end{document}
```

throws numerous other errors but does compile. Even though this doesn't actually solve my problem, it does fix it. Is there a better solution and/or can anyone explain what the problem is here, please?

Comment: It is because `algorithm2e` is actually looking for `krantz` and does something if loaded, but apparently what is does is not compatible with the current version of `krantz`

Comment: I am not so sure this is because of the current version of krantz. I had a look at algorithm2e.sty and it simply modifies some code to acknowledge that \chapter can take more than two arguments in krantz. I was wondering if there was a missing } in that code but didn't see one.

Comment: It goes all wrong. The definition of `\@chapter` in the `krantz.cls` you point to, defines it with `\def\@chapter[#1]#2` and the "fix" `algorithm2e` use `\def\@chapter[#1][#2]#3` and passes on `[#1][#2]{#3}` to the original in the assumption that it takes three arguments, which it does not in the version you use. I'd probably recommend using a different document class.

Comment: What exactly do you need from `algorithm2e` there might be better packages.

Comment: Ah thanks, I see! Unfortunately, the publisher requires krantz class and my coauthor needs algorithm2e!

Comment: Either figure out if there is a newer version of `krantz` of if you do not use `\listofalgorithms` it might be enough to use `\makeatletter\let\@chapter\algocf@original@chapter\makeatother` after loading `algorithm2e`

Comment: The compilation of your document  `krantz` class complains about a lot of things, even without `\RequirePackage{algorithm2e}`.

Comment: @daleif: I think you combine your comments here and transfer it into an answer. I've googled around and found no newer version of the `krantz.cls`. So perhaps the 'fix' is something that is rather new but has been postponed for a long time back to a date when the `krantz.cls` had this 3 - argument definition of `\@chapter`